# docker compose command with which to start the container

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, devops

I'm having this issue that I want those commands (RUN) to run as soon as possible when deploying the container.
But I'm confused with the docker compose yml. How to make it happen.
I just want to do what is below "Modifying permissions" at this site http://docs.grafana.org/installation/docker/#migration-from-a-previous-version-of-the-docker-container-to-5-1-or-later
I get an error when trying to compose it like that:

```
grafana:
  image: grafana/grafana
  container_name: grafana

  RUN: "chown -R root:root /etc/grafana && \ "
  RUN: "chmod -R a+r /etc/grafana && \ "
  RUN: "chown -R grafana:grafana /var/lib/grafana && \ "
  RUN: "chown -R grafana:grafana /usr/share/grafana"
  ports:
    - 3001:3000
  volumes:
    - /root/Stack/tigstack/graf:/var/lib/grafana
  restart:
   always
```

Comment: You can override the entry point with a sh script then return back to your docker run arguments using "exec "$@" see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks very much for the help.  I did a Dockerfile, but I needed a command to run after the container has loaded so  I used "CMD" like this:

```
FROM grafana/grafana:latest
MAINTAINER Denis
VOLUME /root/Stack/tigstack/graf:/var/lib/grafana
EXPOSE 3001:3000
SHELL ["/bin/bash"]
CMD "chmod -R a+r /etc/grafana && \ "
CMD "chown -R grafana:grafana /var/lib/grafana && \ "
CMD "chown -R grafana:grafana /usr/share/grafana"
CMD "chown -R root:root /etc/grafana && \
/home/core/conf/telegraf/telegraf.conf
```

And it worked! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Create a your own `Dockerfile` and give the permission with RUN command there. You cannot use RUN command in docker-compose like the way you have written.

Comment: If these commands are intended to change permissions on the host directory that’s getting bind-mounted into the container, putting them in the Dockerfile won’t be effective; the `volumes:` mount will overwrite anything that happens on that directory tree in the image.